# Highcharts: Styling input-group

Tags: css, angular, highcharts

I'm using the highcharts library (http://www.highcharts.com/) for a project. In this project, the user can change dates through an input group (marked by the red rectangle in the following image):

https://i.stack.imgur.com/3OJpV.jpg

I want to change this input group style by "moving" it to the right, as the red arrow shows in the previous image.

However, changing CSS does not have any effect. This is what I tried:

```
.highcharts-input-group {
  margin-right: 0;
}
```

Any ideas why this is not working?

Thank you!

Comment: Can you put up a fiddle or live example? There are countless factors that could result in setting a right margin to 0 being ineffective for the task you are trying to achieve - it's entirely dependent on any other sibling elements, and the settings of the parent element(s) as well.

Comment: You're right, @jlbriggs. Here is a jsfiddle representing the problem: https://jsfiddle.net/pk4sog67/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look for the [rangeSelector.inputPosition](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock/rangeSelector).

> **inputPosition: Object**
>
> Positioning for the input boxes. Allowed properties are align,
>   verticalAlign, x and y. Defaults to { align: "right" }.

Set `rangeSelector.inputPosition = {x: 0}`

example: https://jsfiddle.net/qjhLexfz/

Comment: Perfect! Thank you, @morganfree.